# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted [New] 2021

Tags: html, django-views, django-forms, http-post, render

I am completely tired with the csrf issue. I have created a sign in form and register form.
I am able to login and logout, even register a user.
The main problem I am facing is the refresh-after-signin.
After signing in, if I refresh the page it simply gives a csrf verification failed error.
I have literally searched for it since past two days with no solution, all the answers are almost 4-5 years older, which are not helping.

This is the views.py signin function.

```
def signin(request):
  if request.method=="POST":
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

    if user is not None:
      login(request,user)
      messages.success(request,"Logged in Successfully!")
      return render(request,'authtest/index.html')
    else:
      messages.error(request,"Bad Credentials")
      return redirect('index')

  return render(request,'authtest/signin.html')
```

This is the HTML form that is returning POST request

```
<form action="{% url 'signin' %}" method="POST">
  <!-- I have no idea what this thing does -->
  {% csrf_token %} 
  <!-- I have no idea what this thing does end -->
  <input type="hidden" id="csrf_token" value='{"csrfmiddlewaretoken": "{{ csrf_token }}"}'>

  <label for="username">UserName</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" required>
  
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" required>

  <button type="submit">SignIn</button>
</form>
```

[image: Refreshing Error]

Comment: This is happening because you are still on the sigin page(check your browser url), so anytime you refresh you're technically still refreshing the sign-in page which then generates the error

Comment: Try redirecting after a successful login rather than rendering a template, that should solve the problem

Comment: Is there any way we can force change the url, since I am using 
return render(...) it should change the url but it is not, also cannot use redirect because it does not send the request along with it. Is there any way we can force change url?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by "i cannot use redirect because it does not send the request along with it", is there some kind of data you want to send to the next page?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to send it the first name and some other details to other page. Is there anyway we can do that??

Comment: Okay, Just redirect to the page you want after a successful login, then on that page use an if statement like this {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}{{ request.user.first_name }}{% endif %}

Comment: It worked, thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Due to some security issues to keep each user's session safe, it is not possible to authenticate and render the url in the same view functions.
Therefore, you must perform the rendering operation in another URL after redirecting
something like this

```
def signin(request): 
   if request.method=="POST":
       ........
       if user is not None:
            ..........
            return redirect ('dashboard')\
```

and that dashboard func is like this

```
def dashboard(request): 
    .......
    return redirect ('dashboard')
```